# Reconstructing an archived SQLite3 database file

Tags: sqlite, zcat

I'm using the method described under the heading *Converting An Entire Database To An ASCII Text File* on [this page](http://www.sqlite.org/cli.html) to archive a sqlite3 database file.

Archiving the database file works fine:

```
$ echo '.dump' | sqlite3 store.db | gzip -c >store.dump.gz
```

Following the instructions on that page (though using `gzcat` instead of `zcat`), I try and reconstruct the archive into a database as follows:

```
$ gzcat store.dump | sqlite3 store_new.db
```

This executes, and `store_new.db` is created, **but it is a Zero KB file**. What am I doing wrong?

(I'm using SQLite 3.7.13 on OS X.)

––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––

*UPDATE:*

Even doing a direct sqlite3 -> sqlite3 dump:

```
echo '.dump' | sqlite3 store.db | sqlite3 store_new.db
```

Results in a Zero KB store_new.db file :-( Any help appreciated!

Comment: Ah ok, I see in the looong dump file that there are two lines in the middle `/**** ERROR: (11) database disk image is malformed *****` with a `ROLLBACK; -- due to errors` at the end. The rollback would explain the zero bytes, right? I deleted these lines and it works fine! (Just have to look into it to see what/if any data is missing now...)